# get url of remote image javascript

Tags: javascript, file, input

I have an `input type="file"`. After clicking an image by the user, I need to display the image immediately without any delay.

For that, I need to get the URL of the image in the remote computer. Can I get the `DATA URI` of the image after the user selects an image from the `input type="file"`?

Comment: @Diodeus I'm so happy you found that, if I hadn't read it I would've suggested going a longer way around (via _Blob_ or even _FileReader_ for the _dataURI_).

Comment: Half of the questions on SO are duplicates. I wish it were easier to find them when asking questions. The auto-suggest is OK, but is very word-dependent.